# VBA To Populate Table Based On Other Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Let me put first here that I am very new to VBA, so my approach here might be completely wrong. I am trying to populate a table through VBA based on data from another sheet.

My output table has the following layout.

[image: OutPutTable]

What I am trying to do is only populate the column of the current month, based on worksheet 2 (CSV data PR) **and paste them in as values.** Reason for that is, worksheet 2's data will be deleted each month with the new month's data.

Worksheet 2 is structured as below:

[image]

So far I have the following piece of code, but it does not do the job. I know how to find the columns I need in the other worksheet, but not how to call them in VBA within the SUMIF function combined with only filling the current month with data.

```
Sub test()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim rw As Long
Dim x, y As Worksheet
Dim Cell As Range
Dim ThisMonth As Date
Dim FindRng As Range

Set x = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CSV data pr")
Set y = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PR")
Set Rngheaders = y.Range("6:6")
Set RngheadersRaw = x.Range("1:1")

ThisMonth = Format(Date, "MM/YYYY")
ystdy = VBA.DateTime.Month(Date)

'MonthCol = RngHeaders2.Find(What:="Month").Column
LastRow = x.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set FindRng = y.Range("6:6").Find(What:=ThisMonth, LookIn:=xlFormulas, lookat:=xlWhole)

If Not FindRng Is Nothing Then
FindRng.Offset(2, 0).Select
Selection.Resize(Selection.Rows.Count + 8).Value = "test"
Else
MsgBox "Error, unable to match " & ThisMonth & " in the specified range", vbCritical
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Does the target table in worksheet PR have a listobject table name or is it simply $E$6:$BL$15 on the worksheet?

Comment: it does not have a listobject table name, it is simply the range

Comment: What is the day of Feb-2019, Mar-2019? Is the full date 1-Feb-2019 and 1-Mar-2019 or is it text?

Comment: I formatted it as text, example: TEXT(C2,"MMM-YYYY")

Comment: Sure, OK. But what is the actual day of the dates/ Is each a different day of the month or or they all 1.

Comment: Ah sorry, these are all different dates.

Comment: Why do you put in formulas if your source data will be deleted soon?

Comment: @JvdV that's actually one of the issues.., I am not sure how to get it to work as the reference would break once the data changes from March to let's say April (as the csv data would be removed and re-uploaded for the new month).